# Textmate navigation shortcuts stopped working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

I use <kbd>Opn</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Opn</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> to navigate between open tabs and all of a sudden it stopped working. It does nothing now. Anyone seen this happen before?

Comment: Try asking your question on SuperUser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to override default Textmate keyboard-shortcuts in "System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts".

Answer (score 1):

TextMate just got a recent update in which the shortcuts for navigating between tabs has been changed to <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>. Just as in Firefox.app or Terminal.app. See this blog post: http://blog.macromates.com/2010/textmate-1-5-10/